# Cron: No input file specified

Tags: php, cron

I ran the following in my cron tab:

```
/home/thanksfo/php -f /home/thanksfo/fastcron.php
```

and the content of fastcron.php is:

```
system("(sleep 10 && /home/thanksfo/php -f /home/thanksfo/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 20 && /home/thanksfo/php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 30 && /home/thanksfo/php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 40 && /home/thanksfo/php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 50 && /home/thanksfo/php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php) &
(sleep 60 && /home/thanksfo/php -f /home/big/public_html/_aweber/admin/cron/cron.php)");
```

what could i change to make it work? It keeps returning no input file specified in the log file.

I made some changes to my code and got the following error:

```
/bin/sh: /home/thanksfo/php: is a directory
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is here and not in `cron.php`?

Comment: Is php in the path? If not, you need to put /usr/local/lib/php -f to you fastcron.php as well, not just php -f

Comment: You cannot execute a directory...

Comment: ring0: how do i check where is the php executable located? I looked at the php config and found this path.

Comment: In a terminal do `which php`